# Передача значения для кнопки в destination view controller

Tags: xcode, ios, uibutton

Есть source view controller и destination view controller. В зависимости от перехода в destination view controller кнопка должна становиться видимой/невидимой. Пробовал такой код, но это не работает (в методе prepare for segue):

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"test"]) {

     UINavigationController *destination = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;

     DestinationViewController *viewController = (DestinationViewController *)destination.topViewController;

     [viewController.testButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Можно просто по условию кнопку не добавлять на контроллер (это если руцями все создаете)

self.myButton.hidden = YES;
(viewController.testButton.hidden = YES)

С другой стороны Вы можете пытаться прятать то чего еще нет. Здесь в коде Вы создаете контроллер, но кнопка еще не создана. Там только свойство. А вот когда будет переход, тогда контроллы и создадутся. Лучше прятать/не создавать по условию, передавая булевую переменную в самом DestinationViewController

Comment: В DestinationViewController во viewDidLoad прячьте кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Надо передать параметр в DestinationViewController, а выставлять его уже внутри на viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1):

В класс DestinationViewController можно добавить свойство. И этим свойством указывать контроллеру скрывать кнопку. UI элементы в view controller инициализируются когда представление готово к отображению на экране.

> @property(nonatomic) BOOL isHideButton;

и реализовать метод

`-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.testButton.hidden = _isHideTestButton;
}`